# XMLStreamReader not able to read field with new line character in it , Rather it take the last line

Tags: java, xml

XMLStreamReader not reading field with new line character in them.

```
private XMLStreamReader reader; 
private void processNodeValue() {
        TreeNode node = stack.peek();
        node.setValue(reader.getText().trim());
     }
```

Comment: Based on the snippet, how someone should be able to know which `XMLStreamReader` implementation you are using?

Comment: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader library has been used

Answer (score 0):

This simple snippet read the new line character

```
StringReader in = new StringReader("<xml>foo\nbar</xml>");
XMLStreamReader reader = XMLInputFactory.newInstance().createXMLStreamReader(in);
while (reader.hasNext()) {
    reader.next();
    if (reader.getEventType() == XMLStreamReader.CHARACTERS) {
        System.out.println(reader.getText());
    }
}
reader.close();
```

output

```
foo
bar
```

If this is not what you are looking for **-->** provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) demonstrating your problem.